# What does it mean to "augment" a set?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactness

I am reading a book Hausdorff Compactifications and I don´t understand the sentence in bold. It is part of proof of the Theorem above (claim 1). I dont undersand in particular, what is meant by "augmenting" the open cover with open set.

Thank you for your help!

---

Theorem 1.11 from Chandler´s book:

1. Closed subsets of compact spaces are compact.
2. Compact subsets of
   Hausdorff spaces are closed.
3. If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous
   and $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is compact.
4. If $f : X \rightarrow Y$
   is one-to-one and continuous, $X$ is compact, and $Y$ is Hausdorff
   then $f$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(X)$.

Proof of 1.

Choose a compact space $X$ and its closed subset $F$. Let $\{\mathcal{O}_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an open cover of $F$.
**We augment $\{\mathcal{O}_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in A}$ with the open set $ X \setminus F$ to obtain an open covering of the compact set $X$.**

Comment: They are adding the one open set $X\setminus F$ to the open cover of $F$, which will hence make an open cover of $X$. So it's a union of the open cover with $\{ X\setminus F \}$

Comment: At the risk of making this simple idea confusing, augmenting an open cover (or [a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity), or a partition for a Riemann sum (but usually *refine* is the term), etc.) could be considered analogous to using [auxiliary lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_line) in school geometry. The fact that both words in English begin with the letter 'a' is entirely irrelevant, by the way. (FYI, Chandler was on my Ph.D. committee.)

Comment: Incidentally, in Chandler's book Lemma 4.8, Theorem 4.10, Theorem 4.12, Corollary 4.13, Proposition 4.15 (all) on pp. 34-36 are true for any nonlimit ordinal $\alpha \geq 1$ and false if $\omega_{\alpha}$ has cofinality $\omega = \aleph_0$ (for example, $\alpha = \aleph_{\omega}).$ Proposition 4.17 on p. 36 is true, but the first sentence of the proof should be changed to "Choose a nonlimit ordinal $\alpha$ for which $|\beta X| < \aleph_{\alpha}.$" **(continued)**

Comment: These results were taken from Problem 9K in **Rings of Continuous Functions** by Gillman/Jerison (1960) and Chandler had overlooked Gillman/Jerison's hypothesis in Problem 9K that $\alpha \geq 1$ is a nonlimit ordinal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author starts with an open cover $\{O_\alpha\mid\alpha\in A\}$ of $F$ and then adds to it the set $X\setminus F$. Since $F$ is closed, $X\setminus F$ is an open set. Therefore, not only is $\{X\setminus F\}\cup\{O_\alpha\mid\alpha\in A\}$  an open cover of $F$, but also  an open cover of $X$, since $(X\setminus F)\cup\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}O_\alpha\supset(X\setminus F)\cup F=X$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I thought "augment" is some mathematical term, but it just mean a union, haha.

Comment: *it just mean a union* --- More accurate than "union" is probably "adding", "including", "extending", or some term that implies an extension of some sort of the original object. For example, we can augment the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$ by adding the point $(0,1),$ which then gives us the function $g(x) = x,$ although in this context one usually says "extended" or "extension" (and not "augment").